# Tesseract OCR fails to detect text/number when image contrast is not good.

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract

When using an image with poor background contrast, tesseract fails to detect number or text. 
Can someone help in preprocessing or anything else required to detect the numbers from this image?
[image]

Comment: Add what you tried until now. It's not a "do-my-job" site.

Comment: if you're sure that your text will be darker than its background, try using `threshold` function for inverted threshold

Answer (score 0):

You should do a contrast low in the préProcess